# Не запускается программа в питоне. По идее она должна выдать наименьшее число а, при котором результат программы будет 10

Tags: python

Ошибку не выдаёт, просто не считает.

```
def f(x):
    a = 3*x + 23
    b = 3*x - 17
    while a != b:
        if a > b:
            a -=b
        else:
            b -=a
    return a
for x in range(1,10000):
    if f(x) == 10:
        print(x)
        break
```

Comment: while цикл идёт бесконечно

Comment: Если `a > 0` и `b > 0`, то в while-цикле Вы будете постоянно отнимать от отрицательного числа, тем самым увеличивая число `a` и всё больше увеличивая разрыв между `a` и `b`. Может быть, стоит поменять логику изменения чисел?

Comment: Это очень хорошая задача. Связь с проблемой остановки, вычислительный эксперимент, обратная трассировка. Не надо минусить. Тут всё сложно.

Comment: @4500zenja, я думаю что функция дана, а задача в том чтобы заставить её вычислить 10. Это совсем не простое дело.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `f` останавливается не для всех `x`. Вы запускаете её для неудачного значения и вечно ждёте результат. Не все программы завершаются. Попробуйте с другого конца.

Пусть `f(x) == 10`. Какими были `a` и `b` когда произошёл `return`? `a = b = 10`. А до этого? Или `a = 20, b = 10` или `a = 10, b = 20`. А до этого? Или `a = 30, b = 10` или `a = 20, b = 30` или `a = 30, b = 20` или `a = 10, b = 30`.

Можно догадаться до двух вещей: чтобы функция завершилась и выдала 10 нужно чтобы в какой-то момент времени выполнились условия `a, b > 0` и `a, b кратны 10`.

Если `a, b > 0` в какой-то момент, алгоритм завершается (доказывается по индукции). Если `b <= 0` функция не завершается никогда. Условие кратности опустим на время. Поставим эксперимент:

```
def f(x):
    a = 3*x + 23
    b = 3*x - 17
    while a != b:
        if a > b:
            a -=b
        else:
            b -=a
    return a

for x in range(1,10000):
    if 3*x + 23 > 0 and 3*x - 17 > 0 and f(x) == 10:
        print(x)
        break
```

> ```
> 9
> ```

Теперь ясно что эксперимент можно было не ставить. Достаточно найти минимальный `x` такой чтобы `a, b` делились на 10 оставаясь положительными. Он и решает задачу.